# realloc not copying first index

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm having some trouble with using the malloc/realloc command with arrays. I've created a small array with some integers in it, and tried to add one value to it by expanding the size with realloc and adding the value, but when I do that the 0 index's value is not preserved and is seen as garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        int n;
        printf("Enter size of array\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int *A = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                A[i] = i + 1;
        }
        *A = realloc(A, sizeof(A)+ sizeof(int));
        A[n] = 1234;
        for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
                printf("%d\n",A[i]);
        }


        return 0;
}
```

and when i run the program this happens:

```
Enter size of array
5
14643216
2
3
4
5
1234
```

Does anyone know why the 0 index of the array is getting this value and not 1?

Comment: `*A = realloc(A` is nonsense, from a run-time point of view, as well as type.  You're saying, reallocate `A`, obtaining a new pointer. Then store that pointer into the first element of the old `A` (which may or may not be the same as the new A). `*A` has type `int`, so you should see a diagnostic that the `void *` return type from `realloc` is being converted to `int` without a cast.

Comment: `A` is the variable which is a pointer type, `*A` is the value the pointer `A` is pointing to, in this case, the first element of the array. So chaging `*A` is actually changing the first element of this array, and not the pointer itself.

Comment: In the `malloc` it works because `*` there is not interpreted as a modifier to `A`, but instead, a modifier to the type, since you are declaring it in the same line.

Comment: ...and sizeof(A) is the size of a pointer type, not the old size of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ gcc a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:12:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         *A = realloc(A, sizeof(A)+ sizeof(int));
            ^
```

Make sure to configure your compiler to emit warnings on code that looks suspicious. Any remotely decent compiler would raise at least a warning, if not an error, on this line. `realloc` returns a pointer, which you're trying to assign to an `int` object.

You need to assign the resulting pointer to `A`, not `*A`. Furthermore, there's another error, which compilers can't warn you about. `sizeof(A)+ sizeof(int)` is too small, and does not make much sense in context. Note that `sizeof(A)` is the size of the *pointer* `A`. There's no way to use `sizeof` to find the number of items in the array that `A` points to, because `sizeof` relies on compile-time information. To extend the array by one element, you need to add `sizeof(int)` to the current allocated size, which is `n*sizeof(int)`, i.e. the new size should be `(n+1) * sizeof(int)`.

In addition, it would be better to use `sizeof(*A)` than `sizeof(int)`. The two are equivalent, but `sizeof(*A)` has the advantage that it'll still be correct if you decide to change the array elements, e.g. to make them `long`.

```
A = realloc(A, (n+1) * sizeof(*A));
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. Pointers and memory allocation for beginners is so intimidating and this helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Write `A = realloc(A, (n + 1) * sizeof(int));` instead of `*A = realloc(A, sizeof(A)+ sizeof(int));`

`*A = ...` will overwrite the value of the  first index with a "address value" if `A` is not moved to another place in memory (undefined behaviour otherwise).

Note that `sizeof(A)` is a constant value (probably 8, and not the amount of memory allocated previously), such that you had a good chance that `realloc` did not move the  memory.

Comment: No. Should be `A = realloc(A, (n + 1) * sizeof(int))`. It's supposed to be adding an additional element to a dynamically allocated array.